# Assistance with BS3 Typeahead with .get as source

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Hello:  I was able to get a simple typeahead working (bootstrap3) where the 'source' is a simple hard coded array.  Here is that code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data =   [{'name':'Gerard'},{'name':'sravan'},{'name':'brent'},]

console.log(data)
var $input = $(".typeahead");
$input.typeahead({
  source: data,
  autoSelect: true

});
```

For the remote source, I have an endpoint which delivers the json of the same array (/portal/billing/locationLookup)

So I am trying to get my typeahead to do a get request against that endpoint for the 'source'

I have been looking at lots of examples but cannot get anything to work so I am hoping someone can help out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("/portal/billing/locationLookup", function(data){
$("#myta").typeahead({ source:data, autoSelect: true });
 },'json');
 })
```